# How to temporary store file in server and retrieve back from `download button` in flask python

Tags: python, flask, web, save

I m trying to save my `to_csv` into `os.path.join` and return the `csv file` from `download button` in HTML page, currently I m getting this `error TypeError: join() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'`, Does anyone excel in flask python, please correct me ~ Appreciate

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
 if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['data_file']
        if not f:
            return "No file"

        
        stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
        csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
        stream.seek(0)
        result = stream.read()
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(result), usecols=[1])
        
        #extract month value
        df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(result))
        matrix2 = df2[df2.columns[0]].to_numpy()
        list1 = matrix2.tolist()
         
        # load the model from disk
        model = load_model('model.h5')
        dataset = df.values
        dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
        scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
        dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
        look_back = 1
        dataset_look = create_dataset(dataset, look_back)
        dataset_look = np.reshape(dataset_look, (dataset_look.shape[0], 1, dataset_look.shape[1]))
        predict = model.predict(dataset_look)
        transform = scaler.inverse_transform(predict)

        X_FUTURE = 12
        transform = np.array([])
        last = dataset[-1]
        for i in range(X_FUTURE):
            curr_prediction = model.predict(np.array([last]).reshape(1, look_back, 1))
            last = np.concatenate([last[1:], curr_prediction.reshape(-1)])
            transform = np.concatenate([transform, curr_prediction[0]])
      
        transform = scaler.inverse_transform([transform])[0]

        dicts = []
        curr_date = pd.to_datetime(list1[-1])
        for i in range(X_FUTURE):
            curr_date = curr_date +  relativedelta(months=+1)
            dicts.append({'Predictions': transform[i], "Month": curr_date})
            

        new_data = pd.DataFrame(dicts).set_index("Month")
        ##df_predict = pd.DataFrame(transform, columns=["predicted value"])

        new_data.to_csv(os.path.join("downloads", index = True, encoding='utf8'))

        labels = [d['Month'] for d in dicts]
            
        values = [d['Predictions'] for d in dicts]

        colors = [ "#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#FEDCBA",
                       "#ABCDEF", "#DDDDDD", "#ABCABC", "#4169E1",
                       "#C71585", "#FF4500", "#FEDCBA", "#46BFBD"]

        line_labels=labels
        line_values=values
        return render_template('graph.html', title='Time Series Sales forecasting', max=17000, labels=line_labels, values=line_values, filename = filename)


@app.route('/download/<filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory("downloads", filename, as_attachment = True)
```

HTML tag >>`<a href="{{ url_for('download', filename=filename) }}">Download</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is caused by this line

```
new_data.to_csv(os.path.join("downloads", index = True, encoding='utf8'))
```

You feed arguments `index` and `encoding` for `os.path.join` rather than `.to_csv` (look at brackets), after fixing that issue you will get

```
new_data.to_csv(os.path.join("downloads"), index = True, encoding='utf8')
```

however this will result in creation of `csv` file named `downloads` or error if `downloads` catalog already exista. Add desired filename as `os.path.join` 2nd argument if you want create file inside `downloads` catalog.

Comment: Appreciate your commend, it did appear another error again, you mean add 2nd argument is like this ? >> `new_data.to_csv(os.path.join("downloads,result.csv"), index = True, encoding='utf8')`, If like this, it only store in local file instead of server, but when I store in local file, do I still can retrieve back the file from `download button` in HTML page?

Comment: You need to deliver 2nd argument to `os.path.join` not bent 1st one, do: `new_data.to_csv(os.path.join("downloads","result.csv"), index = True, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Sorry to say that, I get this error >> `NameError: name 'filename' is not defined`. However, it successfully store `result.csv` into local file `downloads`, But how do I pass my `result.csv` to server so that the user can download from a `download button` in HTML page `<a href="{{ url_for('download', filename=filename) }}">Download</a> ` ?

Comment: Try preparing url to file in your view rather than in template and then pass it there

Comment: Oh, can you like give an example, so that I could have a reference~ thanks